# showing a div element with dynamic id in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display item with dynamic id,but it is not working, some one help me

```
function catshow(qty) {
    var a = qty;
    //alert(a);
    $('.column1#' + a).css({
        'display': 'block'
    });
}
```

Comment: id ? Where in your selector do you try to refer to an id ?

Comment: just $("#" + qty).show() is enough, since id is a unique selector.

Comment: Or `$('#' + qty).show()`. However what you've shown us should work in theory. We need to see more of your code to help you

Comment: Please share your HTML and CSS code as well. Does the element exist?

Comment: <?php 
$sl2=0;
 $tab2=mysql_query("select * from category where tabname='".$tabname ."' ");
 while($li2=mysql_fetch_array($tab2))
 {
 $sl2++;
 $tab3=$li2['category'];?>
<div class="megacol column1" style="width:205px;"  id="<?php echo $a;?> "  >
            <ul class="megamenu level1">
         <li  class="mega ">
          <div class="group">
          <div class="group-content">
       <ul class="megamenu level2">
     <li  class="mega ">
<div class="group">

Comment: <div class="group-title mgh"><a   class="mega first haschild"  title="<?php echo $tab3; ?>" style="cursor:pointer;"><span class=            "menu-title"><?php echo $tab3; ?></span></a></div>
        <div class="group-content">
          <ul class="megamenu level3">
          <?php 
    
    $lst=mysql_query(" select * from subcategory1 where category='".$tab3."' group by subcategory");
while($pt=mysql_fetch_array($lst)) 
{
?>

Comment: <li  class="mega first test" style="width:200px;"><a href="all.php?subcatname1=<?php echo $pt['subcategory']?>"  class="mega first"   title="<?php echo $pt['subcategory']?>"><span class="menu-title"><?php echo $pt['subcategory']?></              span></a>
          </li>
         <?php  }?>
           </ul>
           </div>
           
          </li>
        </ul>
         </div>
           </div>
             </li>
            </ul>
            </div>

Comment: <script> 
   
  function catshow(qty)  {      
    
      
    
    
    
  //alert(a);
  
  $('.column1#' +qty).hide();
    
   
      }
      </script>     
<?php } ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>

<?php }?>

Comment: this is all my code as i use

Comment: please add the content of your comment as formatted code to the question. You can't expect reading comments of the people who help you

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#" + qty).css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `{ }` ..

```
function catshow(qty) {
    var a = qty;
    //alert(a);
    $('.column1#' + a).css(
        'display': 'block'
    );

    //or

    $('.column1#' + a).show();
}
```

Comment: sir i applied it but no result yut

Comment: Please add some html snippet.

Comment: i have add html above